# How do you add a PrimeFaces facet footer that is blank?

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I'm using primefaces6.1.  I have a one column scrollable dataTable where I would prefer to use a facet for the header and footer as opposed to using the dataTable header and footer.  They have a better appearance.  The header displays the name.  The footer sort of frames out the scrollable list's bottom.  But, I want to show the footer as a blank.

```
<f:facet name="footer"></f:facet>
```

The tags above will not display.  It seems the only way to display the footer is to put something inside of the facet tags.  What would I put in the facet footer to display a blank footer?

Comment: Maybe `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Wow, that was too simple.  Yup, it worked just fine.  Thank you Kukeltje.

Comment: You could have put anything in there and 'hide' it with css ;-)

Comment: Yes, that would have worked too.  Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `&nbsp;` in there. it is a solution and works like a charm.

Comment: That's what I did, see comments above.

Comment: I know, but stackoverflow works by having (good) answers. Therefor I created one but after your comment, I reformulated